# Can I read specific cell value using pandas.ExcelFile?

Tags: pandas, parsing, cell

I can read whole rows of table using this:

```
myexcel = pd.ExcelFile("my_Excel.xlsx")

my row = myexcel.parse(2, skiprows=14, skipfooter= 2).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Using this and some additional params I could read a single specific cell value. But is it possible to just read this single cell from sheet by providing just cell coordinates(let's say `cell('J10')`)?

**UPDATE**

I would like to get a solution using pd.ExcelFile if possible...

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html if you read the documentation you would be able to work this out. If you really want to do this you can specify the column and the rows to get a single cell from an excel sheet.

Comment: @WoodyPride I used `usecols` param to narrow everything down to a single cell, but how could I assign that single value to a single variable as a single value? Because rightnow I get Series...

Comment: you can try `.values` to get the (only) value from the series